# Configuring events on Xmega

Tags: avr, xmega, atxmega

Is it necessary to enable the interrupt for a given event source in order for the event to fire, or is it only necessary to select the source from the event system?

To clarify, I am asking about the Xmega Event System, not the interrupt system.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to enable the interrupt for a given event source in order for the event to fire

No. One of the features of the XMEGA event system is that it specifically doesn't *need* interrupts.  Programs for other architectures which would need to use interrupts to cause X to be detected and then trigger Y, can in some cases (depending on X and Y) use the event system on XMEGA without using interrupts.

I remember reading that all events that cause interrupts can also generate events, although I didn't try to prove that myself. Also a situation (say a timer overflow) can be programmed to generate both an event *and* an interrupt. Again, that advanced usage isn't something I have proved myself, but I don't doubt the claim.

> is it only necessary to select the source from the event system

Using events requires more than just selecting the source. In broad terms, you have to decide on the event source (event generator); the event target (event user); the event channel (mux number); and configure all three in the setup code. Of course there are lots of details "below" that overview, depending on the peripherals involved and the system design.

The event system is described in section 6 of the [Atmel XMEGA A Manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8077.pdf).

Comment: Excellent, that's what I thought. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use an interrupt to trigger some action in your program, you must enable the appropriate interrupt, and provide an interrupt handler routine to deal with thte interrupt.

If you won't use interrupts, but just poll the inputs in your main program, you do not enable interrupts.

Comment: I know how the interrupts work, I'm asking about the Xmega Event System.